# Switch between views in different navigation controllers

Tags: ios, swift

I have 2 top-level view controllers each with their own navigation controller. I also have a MenuViewController which is added to each of the top-level view controllers upon viewDidLoad like this:

```
    var storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    var vc : MenuViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MenuViewController") as MenuViewController
    addChildViewController(vc)
    menuView.addSubview(vc.view)
    vc.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

In the MenuViewController, you can switch between the two top-level view controllers. I'm currently using this code to switch between them:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let vc : HomeViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HomeViewController") as HomeViewController
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
        self.presentViewController(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
        let vc : FoodCraftsViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FoodCraftsViewController") as FoodCraftsViewController
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
        self.presentViewController(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

My worry is that every time I switch between views using the menu, it's allocating additional memory and not removing the previous view from memory. What's the efficient way to ensure I'm not re-creating view controllers/wasting memory every time I switch top-level views with the menu?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep a reference to an instance of `HomeViewController` and `FoodCraftsViewController` in your `MenuViewController`. Instantiate it if the pointer is unset, otherwise use the existing value in your `presentViewController` call.

Comment: Is it that easy? I didn't think that would work because each time the top-level view controller loads, it creates a new instance of the MenuViewController.

Comment: How many times does your top-level view controller load? Maybe I misunderstood your architecture. Are you creating a `MenuViewController` inside each of your `HomeViewController` and `FoodCraftsViewController`s?

Comment: Yes, I'm creating a MenuViewController instance inside both top-level view controllers, but both view controllers won't be loaded at the same time. I'm doing this because of an animation I'm doing in these view controllers where the status bar hides at the same time the main view animates down partially off the screen, revealing the MenuViewController underneath. Would your method still work with preventing unnecessary allocation/instantiation?

Comment: It would still work as long as you also only ever created the `MenuViewController` once. Consider using a class method for "Shared `MenuViewController`".

Comment: Great, thanks Ian! Do you mean to make MenuViewController a singleton?

Comment: Yes. You may be required to call `removeFromParentViewController`.

Comment: Quick question: I've changed MenuViewController to be a singleton via the sharedInstance class variable. How would I change the first bit of code I pasted to include the storyboard view of MenuViewController, but also only its singleton instance?

Comment: Your singleton should be created using `storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`.

Comment: Ian, everything is working correctly, but I'm seeing the memory gradually increase as I change views when looking at Instruments. Could I send you the project to take a look?